# Unintended effect of closing square bracket on Spanish keyboard in Mathematica online

Tags: keyboard, mathematica-online

I have only just started using **Mathematica Online** and I have encountered a problem already with the ubiquitous closing square bracket `]` using a Spanish key board. I am working on a laptop using Windows 7 and the way to input the closing square bracket into a notebook is by using <kbd>ALT GR</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> and hitting the key two positions to the right of the 'p' (same key where the `]` is located on a US keyboard). When I do that, it doesn't insert the square bracket, but an orange `=` sign with a small input box  instead (for natural language input I assume).

There seem to have been similar problems with older versions of the desktop version of *Mathematica*, but the work arounds I could find are not applicable to *Mathematica Online*. Short of copying and pasting the closing bracket from elsewhere into the notebook or remapping the keys on the keyboard, is there any other way to resolve this? Has anybody else encountered this problem? Obviously, since I am working on a laptop, switching keyboards isn't a straightforward option.

Thanks!!

Gilbert

Comment: Probably the same problem as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132724/5467). The good new : this problem is solved, at least on Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 2):

In OS X, I have not been able to reproduce your problem.

But on Windows I use: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> to insert `]` when I need it. It is slower but it works. You just need to press numbers on Numeric Pad. I hope your laptop have one or if not use <kbd>Fn</kbd> to access a virtual numPad.

[Here](http://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/punctuation-alt-codes.php) is a guide of other codes and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) is a Wikipedia article explaining it.

Lets hope Wolfram solves this issue soon.