# Mathematica Online, annoying braces

Tags: mathematica-online

I have the trial of Mathematica Online, and this is already starting to annoy me. I'm desesperately trying to put a brace but a text field comes up and I can't manage to put a brace, it interpretates it as a character.

I'm trying to put the expression `Plot[x^2,{x,-5,5}]` but it doesn't work. It works when I copy/paste it

Comment: I have a similar problem on the Wolfram Devloment Platform. Can you confirm that it concerns the closing brace (`}`). This problem depends of the kind of keyboard. Mine is AZERTY. What is yours ?

Comment: I have the same, yup.

Comment: I have reported the problem to Wolfram Research. Here is the answer : "The issue has been reported before and our developers are aware of it. One obvious workaround for now would be to type in the address bar of your browser and copy paste in your notebook. We keep investigating this further and if we find any concrete information we will contact you again." (February 2016. Since : nothing.)

Answer (score 8):

This old problem is solved, at least on the wolfram development platform.

I guess it's the same for Mathematica Online & Co.

Tried on Chrome.

**Edit (08.02.2019) :**

It works on Firefox now !

Comment: It doesn't work on Firefox

Comment: Now it works on Firefox !